# Pseudocode assignment

Tags: pseudocode

I have been given an assignment and I am new to pseudocode. Can someone check or fix my code please.

(TASK)
Task 1 – becoming a member of Friends of Seaview Pier
Set up a system to enable people to become members of Friends of Seaview Pier and for each new
member enter:

- their first name and last name
- whether or not they wish to work as a volunteer
- if they choose to volunteer, identify the area from:

  - the pier entrance gate
  - the gift shop
  - painting and decorating
- the date of joining
- whether or not they have paid the $75 fee.

All of this information needs to be stored using suitable data structures.

```
INPUT← “name”

OUTPUT← “Work as a volunteer”
IF “no” THEN END

ELSE ask for location

INPUT← “Pier entrance gate”, “The gift shop”, “Painting and decorating”

THEN 

OUTPUT← “Date of joining”

INPUT← “Date”
    THEN ask for payment

    IF paid “$75” 

OUTPUT←”Thank you”

END

ELIF “not paid”
OUTPUT← “BYE”
```

In preparation for the examination candidates should attempt the following practical tasks by writing
and testing a program or programs.
Friends of Seaview Pier is an organisation devoted to the restoration and upkeep of a pier in the
town. A pier is a wooden structure that provides a walkway over the sea. The pier requires regular
maintenance and the friends of the pier need to raise money for this purpose.

Members of Friends of Seaview Pier each pay $75 per year, as a contribution to the pier’s running costs.
This entitles them to free admission to the pier throughout the year. They can also volunteer to help run the
pier, by working at the pier entrance gate, working in the gift shop, or painting and decorating.
To provide additional income, the pier’s wooden planks can be sponsored. A brass plaque, which
contains a short message of the sponsor’s choice, is fitted to a plank on the pier, for a donation of $200.

Write and test a program or programs for the Friends of Seaview Pier:

- Your program or programs must include appropriate prompts for the entry of data. Data must be
  validated on entry.
- All outputs, including error messages, need to be set out clearly and understandably.
- All variables, constants and other identifiers must have meaningful names.
  You will need to complete these three tasks. Each task must be fully tested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Pasting content from a word processor usually doesn't retain the desired format.  I translated some of the formatting to Markdown.  Please check my changes so it is consistent with your intent.

Comment: As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, you're not asking a question. Note that "do my homework!" is not a suitable question (it's not a question at all), but that's also explained in the given links. It could also help if you looked at the description of the tag that you applied, maybe that contains a bit of general info on the topic.